# Amazon API -- how to fetch all reviews of a particular user

Tags: amazon-product-api

There is now a mechanism in the Amazon Product API to retrieve all reviews for a particular product. I'm interested in the opposite: fetch all reviews done by a particular user, for all the products she has reviewed. Is this possible directly from Amazon, or are there any third party APIs that allow this? Thanks.